# guild argument in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, disco

This is My code, obviously, something is wrong... I don't know where I would put the guild argument when defining the command but it doesn't look like I put it un the right spot

````
async def unban(guild, ctx, *, member):
  banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

  for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user
    if(user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      await ctx.send(f'Unbanned **{user}** !')
      await user.send(f"You have been unbanned from **{guild.name}")
      return```
````

Comment: Why do you want to make `guild` a required argument? That does not make any sense here. Also, your `user.send` part will not work as the user and bot do not share a server after the ban anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So you can actually take out the guild requirement in this piece `async def unban(guild, ctx, *, member):` and just make it `async def unban(ctx,*,member: discord.Member):`

You need to put member: discord.Member instead of just member!

Then put ctx in front of `{guild.name}` so it looks like `{ctx.guild.name}`

Then in all it should look like this!

```
@client.command()
async def unban( ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
  banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

  for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user
    if(user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      await ctx.send(f'Unbanned **{member}** !')
      await member.send(f"You have been unbanned from **{ctx.guild.name}")
      return
```

Comment: Since this is an unban command, would using `discord.Member` in this case be suitable? Since the user is already banned and does not share the guild anymore, hence no `discord.Member` instance. I suggest using `discord.Object` in this case by passing the user ID, and calling `guild.unban()` by passing that as the argument. You can also handle the part to check if the member is banned since it raises `discord.NotFound` if the member is not found/banned without the usage of `ctx.guild.bans`

Comment: oh you are totally right, you actually do not need to call the member argument, because the user isn’t actually in the server.